# Spectrum of OFDM with raised cosine window(overlap and add)

Tags: frequency-spectrum, ofdm

I'm having trouble observing OFDM with a raised cosine (RC) window in Matlab.

I know how to generate an OFDM signal with a raised cosine (RC) window, I just don't understand when the last W samples of an OFDM symbol are added to the first W samples of the successive symbol, its spectrum changes compared with no overlap(the OOB is nearly same with no windowing).

I don't know if something wrong with my matlab code about how to see overlapped windowing-OFDM, or overlap would influence per symbol's spectrum?

Comment: @ Deve Could you please answer my question?

Comment: I think we need more info. Is the window applied in time or frequency domain? Can you desribe it mathematically? What outcome do you excpect? I expect the spectrum to change, this is usually the purpose of windowing.